# Office 365 Upload User Photo

Tags: office365, photo, profile, sharepoint-online

We want to upload photos for users from a third party application / site. The user may or may not have a Office 365 Exchange mailbox. The user may or may not be an external user.

We are currently uploading profile photos to the SharePoint Online User Profile Service, but are finding the results to be extremely inconsistent across tenants for different users (with / without Exchange mailbox and Internal / external users).

So, which API (officially) should be used to upload a profile photo? Should it be Exchange, SharePoint UPS, Delve or Microsoft Graph?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at uploading it into Exchange Online as that appears to be where the Microsoft provided PowerShell command ([Set-UserPhoto](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj218694(v=exchg.160).aspx)) runs out of.

To get around the fact that some of the accounts may not have mailboxes, you can provision them, set photo, then de-provision them.

Comment: The option of provision and then de-provision is not an option. This is a third party app and we cannot do that. If you have 70'000 users of the app and a lot of photo updates it is not a good option either.